# Corona pass parameter in gotoScene

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I refer to corona website [reference](http://coronalabs.com/blog/2012/04/27/scene-overlays-and-parameter-passing/) using these to pass parameters to another scene.

### main.lua

```
local options =
        {
            effect = "slideLeft",
            time = 800,
            params = { var1 = "custom", myVar = "another" }
        }

        storyboard.gotoScene( "notificationPage", options )
```

then on my other scene

### notificationPage.lua

```
function scene:enterScene( event )
   local group = self.view

local params = event.params
print( params.var1 ) 
print( params.myVar )
end
```

it return error `attempt to index local 'params' (a nil value)`. why is that ? and how do i do it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It should be placed in "createScene" instead of "enterScene".
And as you may read in Corona Docs "This library is planned for deprecation. If you are starting a new project, you should use the composer.* scene management library instead."

Answer (score 0):

It's in the 'createScene' event handler only, try this code:

```
function oScene:createScene( oEvent )    
    local oGroup = self.view
    local aParams = oEvent.params

    if aParams then
        print (aParams.var1)
        print (aParams.myVar)
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use scene:create function:

```
function scene:create( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local params = event.params
    print( params.var1 ) 
    print( params.myvar )

end
```

you can download scene template from coronalabs.com